# Listview row getting highlighted making the widgets invisible

Tags: android, android-listview

I have generated a Listview using `fortysevendegree swipelistview` library. I want to highlight the selected Listview row with a specific color and not the default highlighter in android. i have done the following code but my whole row gets the color and the widgets get masked. If i remove the `android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"` there is no Highlight on the row. Can anyone please tell me what to do? My codes are as below::

myactivity.xml

```
  <com.fortysevendeg.swipelistview.SwipeListView
         android:id="@+id/swipy"
         android:layout_width="fill_parent"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         swipe:swipeFrontView="@+id/front"
         swipe:swipeBackView="@+id/back"
         android:focusable="true"
         android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
         android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
         android:drawSelectorOnTop="true"
         android:dividerHeight="1dp"
          swipe:swipeMode="right"
        />
```

listselector.xml in drawable folder

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_normal" android:state_activated="false"/>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_activated="true"/>
  </selector>
```

list_item_bg_normal.xml in drawable

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
  android:startColor="@color/list_background"
  android:endColor="@color/list_background"
  android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

list_item_bg_pressed.xml in drawable

```
  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
<gradient
  android:startColor="@color/list_background_pressed"
  android:endColor="@color/list_background_pressed"
  android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

Comment: Simply change this color: `list_background_pressed` in colors.xml... and you don't need gradients, if the start and the end colors are the same: use **solid**, instead (better performance)

Comment: Well I don;t have trouble with getting the highlight on the row..But my textviews and Imagevies are getting masked by the Highlight i.e they are not visible when the row is highlighted. any suggestions

Comment: Make your colors transparent by adding alpha hexcode(i.e #aarrggbb) for example #99ff0000 for transparent red.